# JavaScript (Node.js) -- retrieving date from MySQL column is a day behind

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, date, time

I have a Node.js server running as an API server for a service I'm working on for a company.

The MySQL server it connects to stores dates for when an event starts, insertion works perfectly and you can see the correct date from MySQL Workbench and the command line tool. However, when I go to retrieve the date column from Node.js, the output is a day behind for the timezone I'm currently in even though it's the same timezone as the server and MySQL server.

Any ideas?

---

I also wrote a small script that I ran on the server to get example output:

- **Event name**: Aidan's Birthday
- **Start date**: Sat Jul 27 2013 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
- **Milliseconds**: 1374969600000
- **UTC**: Sun, 28 Jul 2013 00:00:00 GMT
- **Day of month**: 27
- **ISO String**: 2013-07-28T00:00:00.000Z
- **Locale string**: Sat Jul 27 2013 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)

The start date is a day behind, the UTC date is right on (it should be July 28th, which is what MySQL Workbench displays, and what was originally inserted).

Comment: How are the Dates being outputted when they appear "*a day behind*?"

Comment: @JonathanLonowski the server sends the time in milliseconds (since epoch) and the date is a day behind for the timezone in which is was originally for.

Comment: The start date is in local time and UTC is in GMT, but they are both referring to the same point in time. Can you be more clear about what specifically your script receives and what you are expecting it to receive?

Comment: @mdd061000 yeah; well I expect the local time to be the same as what was originally inserted. The server inserted July 28th originally (and it should've been from the same timezone) but gets July 27th back later.

Comment: How was July 28th inserted? It seems like it was inserted in a way that makes mysql believe that is a UTC datetime as opposed to local.

Comment: @mdd061000 I've tried two things:

<br/> 1.) The client sends the time in milliseconds, the server converts that to a Date object and inserts that.

<br/> 2.) Using NOW(), CURDATE(), or CURTIME() functions from MySQL as insertions.

<br/> The time is displayed correctly when viewing the database table from MySQL Workbench, just not when it gets pulled in JavaScript and sent in milliseconds to the client.

Comment: can you post the javascript code you are using to retrieve the date and the specific SQL statement that you're using to store the date?

Answer (score 0):

Unless it was posted a long time ago, I had the same problem. I have detected the problem: when removing the time part in the datetime, hour was automatically set to "00:00:00" by MySQL. Due to UTC time was not set properly, it was substracting one hour, so it was 23:00:00 from previous day in my case. Removing again the time part, that resulted in a day before. It is necessary to set timezone in MySQL connection.